# Vuex mapGetters not displaying titileds

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have a Vuex app with CLI3, and testing the getters with a couple of items but not displaying them, here is code below, everything else is OK  but not showing the two titles. The todo module is imported OK in store index.js and doesnt seem to be any other problems

Todos.Vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h3>Todo</h3>
    <div class="todos">
      <div v-for="todo in allTodos" v-bind:key="todo.id" class="todo">
        {{ todo.title }}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
import { mapGetters } from "vuex";
export default {
  name: "Todo",
  computed: mapGetters(["allTodos"])
};
</script>



 /* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */
console.log("Todos Works");
// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
import axios from "axios";

const state = {
  todos: [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: "Todo One"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: "Todo Two"
    }
  ]
};

const getters = {
  allTodos: state => state.todos
}
```

(also exported)

App.vue

```
[enter image description here][1]
    <template>
      <div id="app">
        <div class="container">
          <Todos />
        </div>
      </div>
    </template>

    <script>
    import Todos from "./components/Todos.vue";

    export default {
      name: "App",
      components: {
        // eslint-disable-next-line vue/no-unused-components
        Todos
      }
    };
    </script>


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8nhG.jpg

So just wanting those two titles but not showing. Everything else is fine?

Thanks
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing something, you need to use the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) with mapGetters.

```js
<script>
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'
export default {
  name: 'Todo',
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(['allTodos'])
  }
}
</script>
```

[Reference](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#the-mapgetters-helper)

Comment: Yes got that now Thanks